# How can i access title content from jquery

Tags: jquery, image, image-gallery, photo-gallery, prettyphoto

i am using pretty photo for my gallery. i want some description to be in the pop up.i give it in gref title tag (test)
Now i want the title content in my jquery. how can i access it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
var title = $('element').attr('title');
```

Comment: actually i want the title tag for a href . But the page contains so many hrefs. i give id=test for the href tag and used as $('#test').attr('title'). Then the page hangs and gives javascript error.

Comment: If there are multiple elements using `id="test"` then it's invalid, you must change `id` to `class`.